# Using $_GET with brackers in URL

Tags: php

I have the following code...

```
<?php
if ($_GET['custom_fields%5Bcartredirectmb%5D'] == 'test')
{ header("Location: http://www.google.com"); exit(); }
?>
```

I just need this code to get the parameter 'custom_fields[cartredirectmb]' and redirect based on its value.

It looks like it's hung up on the brackets in the parameter.  I've tried using urlencode, but I'm not getting anywhere.  I assume there's a simple answer to this get working.

Feedback?  Thanks!

Comment: you should use rather urldecode() than encode.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you get when you do: `echo $_GET['custom_fields']['cartredirectmb'];`?

Answer (score 1):

PHP automatically expands array expressions in the URL into the `$_GET` variable.

The following variable in the URL,

```
?custom_fields[cartredirectmb]=test
```

can be accessed through the `cartredirectmb` key, in the `custom_fields` array in the URL.

```
$_GET['custom_fields']['cartredirectmb']
```